# Parsing data from loop to modal in same view always get last data

Tags: laravel

I want to send my data from a loop to show some detail in the modal. But the modal always get the last value from the loop.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Kode Nota</th>
            <th>Tanggal Transaksi</th>
            <th>Nama Kosumen </th>
            <th>Nomor Telpon </th>
            <th>Status Transaksi</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($transaksi as $data)
        <tr>
            <td><?= $data->kodeNota?></td>
            <td><?= $data->tanggalTransaksi?></td>
            <td><?= $data->namaKonsumen ?></td>
            <td><?= $data->noTelpKonsumen ?></td>
            <td><?= $data->statusTransaksi ?></td>
            <td><a data-item="{{ $data->kodeNota }}" class="btn btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDetail">Detail</a></td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is the modal to show the detail

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalDetail" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="detailModal" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body edit-content">
            <h5 class="text-center">Detail Transaki {{$data->kodeNota}}</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you access the `$data` variable outside and after the loop?

Comment: make unique modal id for each data of loop

Answer (score 1):

You can do this two ways.

**Method 1:**
Get the desired object id on click send  ajax request to get data. Parse / write data to your modal body and then open the modal.

**Method 2:**
`This is tricky and easier but very bad approach`. generate individual unique modal for each row by using individual unique id.

```
@foreach($transaksi as $data)
        <tr>
            <td><?= $data->kodeNota?></td>
            <td><?= $data->tanggalTransaksi?></td>
            <td><?= $data->namaKonsumen ?></td>
            <td><?= $data->noTelpKonsumen ?></td>
            <td><?= $data->statusTransaksi ?></td>
            <td><a data-item="{{ $data->kodeNota }}" class="btn btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDetail-{{$data->id}}">Detail</a></td>
        </tr>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalDetail-{{$data->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="detailModal" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body edit-content">
            <h5 class="text-center">Detail Transaki {{$data->kodeNota}}</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I tried it sometimes ago, to put the modal in thee loop, but it only show the first data

Comment: i did a small mistake on closing ". i update my code. please try again. And you have to make sure data-target will be generated as "#modalDetail-1", "#modalDetail-2",... such way and modal id will be same as data-target

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Jquery easily. In your button add custom attribute like you did already, `data-item="{{ $data->kodeNota }}"` but instead of send one value, send full object if you want to populate others value in your modal like below.

```
<td><a data-item="{{ $data }}" class="btn btn-block details-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDetail">Detail</a></td>
```

add an event function in your modal button,

```
$(document).on('click', '.details-button', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var item = $(this).data('item');
      // for debug purpose you can console.log(item) and can actaully see you get the item object or not.

      $('#modalDetail .text-center').text(item.kodeNota);

      //update if you give your label a id
      $('#modalDetail #kodeNota').text(item.kodeNota);

      // you can populate your other data here
      $('#modalDetail .text-center-two').text(item.other_data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately, the data is not showing in the modal. This is a right way to get the data from jquery right? `<label class="text-center"></label>`

Comment: you can give your label a id like `<label class="text-center" id="kodeNota"></label>` and try to populate data using id and it should work i am using this method in my project.